# Motorola Xoom Screen Pixels have changed after software update

Tags: android, screen, device, pixel, xoom

The screen pixels for the morotola xoom were 1280 x 800 or 800 x 1280 before the software updated to the newwest version, now it is 1280 x 752 and then 800 x 1232

anyone know why?

Comment: the status bar at the bottom is probably no longer included in the measurable pixels

Comment: This question is not valuable.This site is for programming Q&A.

Comment: It is valuable to android programmers

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/ better place to ask this question.

Comment: Not really. UX is for creating great UI, the question why something like the screen size changed is more programming related not UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing from which version to which version you updated I think the reason is that the actionbar/statusbar is now excluded from the screen resolution. It was done to reduce the problems for developers when calculation viewports for games and other screen intense applications.